# Erro ao fazer o deploy de projeto laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view

Ao fazer o `deploy` da minha aplicação em uma maquina Linux retorna um erro informando que a `view` não foi encontrada

```
"View [auth.login] not found."
```

Porém a `view` está na pasta, e em seguida a pagina recarrega e um outro erro é informando inclusive o `path` (caminho) antigo da maquina

```
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\usebit_admin\storage\framework/sessions/71d4ahDlA4Di04lO03Zgri7g3RqUYl4yxfh1bi2M): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Na minha maquina local funciona perfeitamente, o que são estes erros e como eu os conserto ?

Comment: Como foi feito esse procedimento?

Comment: Tente renomear a pasta "vendor" para "vendor.bkp" e então execute o seguinte comando na raiz do projeto `composer update --no-scripts`, e teste o projeto novamente.

Comment: segui o seguinte procedimento para deploy https://udemy-assets-on-demand2.udemy.com/2018-12-15_10-48-34-5d2debde0d335ad517a666b3b5843b64/original.pdf?nva=20190208023010&download=True&filename=deploy-linux.pdf&token=02e40aa1e0e2786d0829f

Comment: Tenta rodar os seguintes comandos na raiz do projeto, `composer dump-autoload` e `php arsisan cache:clean`e ve se o erro vai continuar

Comment: ainda não consegui resolver são os mesmos erros

Comment: você está utilizando git? Talvez esqueceu de adicionar os arquivos? `git add .`

Answer (score 0):

Possíveis motivos:

1. Está lendo o arquivo compilado do seu laravel. Você pode limpar utilizando:

```
php artisan clear-compiled  
php artisan view:clear # limpar apenas views
```

2. Se utiliza git, pode ter esquecido de adicionar o(s) arquivo(s)?

```
git add .
```